# How to access Windows Wamp64 www directories from XAMPP in Linux for easy OS migration

Tags: linux, apache, xampp, wampserver, lamp

I want to access my wamp64 web directory from xampp in linux so that i dont have to copy paste files before switching OSs.
i have changed

> lamp/etc/httpd.conf

as, web directory & documentroot from

> "/opt/lampp/htdocs"

to

> "/media/user/******/wamp64"

(my prefered directory).
But i cant access that directory.
i have used the command

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /media/user/******/wamp64
```

But to no avail.
it is showing **Access forbidden**

Answer (score 0):

Your wamp directory is in USB Device ?
If it is try this identify USB path:

```
fdisk -l
```

And did you try to mount your device ?

Comment: My wamp directory is not in a usb drive rather in my windows partition.
And i'm not a savvy Linux user. I don't know what you meant by mounting. Is'n my partition already mounted?

Comment: You can just use "mount" command.
Identify your participation with "fdisk -l"
And use for exemple
"mount /dev/sda4 /mnt"

After this you will access your partition in /mnt directory